# cannot insert datetime in visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I have one question and was wondering if someone could help..
I have created a program in vb net. When I press a button then it should insert in my sql database in the column "date" the current date and time. I use for this purpose the following code :

```
query1 = "insert into visit(visit,textfile,p_id) VALUES('" & Date.Today & "','" & s & "',(select patient.p_id from patient where (patient.name=('" & ComboBox1.Text & " '))))"
```

Well it does its job but when i look in my database in the column 'visit' it displays only zeros.

Any ideas?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: You should use SQL Parameters instead of string concatenation to build up your query.

Answer (score 2):

Use a parameterized query (this example is for Sql Server). In this way you don't need to worry how to quote a date, a string or what is the correct decimal separator required by the database.
Moreover you avoid any problem with [Sql Injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work)

```
 query1 = "insert into visit(visit,textfile,p_id) VALUES(@p1, @p2, " & _ 
          "(select patient.p_id from patient where patient.name=@p3)"

 Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = new MySqlCommand(query1, connection)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Date.Today)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", s)
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", ComboBox1.Text)
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: i have tried this but i gives e error in sql command...do i have to import anything?

Comment: it says: operator = is not defined for types'mysqldata.mysqlclient.mysqlcommand and mysql.data.mysqlclient.mysqlcommand

Comment: :) ok no problem,but unfortunately it says that there is an error in mysql near 1.

Comment: my fault i mistyped it...but for some reason it adds duplicate rows and although it is displayed properly it is saved with today date and 12:00 no matter how man times i click it.

Comment: Do not worry how the tool that show the database info presents a date value. It is common to show for datetime fields also the value 12.00 in the output.

Comment: First of all thank you so much for your help...well yes but shouldn't is say instead of 12:00 the current time?..Anyway problem solved .AGain THANKS!!

Comment: If you want to store also the current time you need to pass DateTime.Now instead of DateTime.Today....

Comment: Thank you so much for you help..you were really clear and helpfull.